# Snowflake Parquet Copy Into NULL_IF

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

I have a staged parquet file in and s3 location. I am attempting to parse the parquet file into a relational table, the field i'm having an issue with is a `timestamp_ntz` field.

In the file, there is a field called "due_date", and while most of the time it is populated with data, on occasion there is an empty string like below:

`"due_date":""`

The error that i'm receiving is **'Failed to cast variant value "" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ.'**

Using the NULL_IF parameter in the copy into is not yielding any results and is set to:

`file_format = (TYPE='PARQUET' COMPRESSION = SNAPPY BINARY_AS_TEXT = true TRIM_SPACE = false NULL_IF = ('\\N','NULL','NUL','','""'))`

I have seen other users replace the NULL's in the SELECT portion of the COPY INTO statement, but this would be a hard to implement option due to the fields being dynamic.

Could anyone shed any light on this, other than the knowledge that empty strings shouldn't form part of parquet?

Full query below: `USE SCHEMA MY_SCHEMA; COPY INTO MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE(LOAD_DATE,ACCOUNTID,APPID,CREATED_AT,CREATED_ON,DATE,DUE_DATE,NUMEVENTS,NUMMINUTES,REMOTEIP,SERVER,TIMESTAMP,TRACKNAME,TRACKTYPEID,TRANSACTION_DATE,TYPE,USERAGENT,VISITORID) FROM (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),$1:accountId,$1:appId,$1:created_at,$1:created_on,$1:date,$1:due_date,$1:numEvents,$1:numMinutes,$1:remoteIp,$1:server,$1:timestamp,$1:trackName,$1:trackTypeId,$1:transaction_date,$1:type,$1:userAgent,$1:visitorId  FROM @my_stage ) PATTERN = '.*part.*' file_format = (TYPE='PARQUET' COMPRESSION = SNAPPY BINARY_AS_TEXT = true TRIM_SPACE = false NULL_IF = ('\\N','NULL','NUL','','""'));`

Comment: What about converting it during SELECT using IFF as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71157835/check-for-null-values-while-finding-timestamps-from-datetime/71158855#71158855)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP. Since TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP does not accept variant, you need to cast it to string first:

```
TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP($1:due_date::string)
```

instead of just

```
$1:due_date
```

If the due_date is empty, the result will be NULL in the timestamp field in the target table after insert.